# HTML: Relative Link without Parameters

Tags: html, href, relative-url

I have a page name `index.php`. It is in the folder name `test`. So if I call `localhost/test` I can see the page.

I have links in the page that pass parameters:

```
<a href="?id=1">Link1</a>
<a href="?id=2">Link2</a>
```

So the URL is `localhost/test/?id=1`

After that I want to link to the root page (index.php) but I don't want to use `href="index.php"`. I want a link for root page without parameters. So when the user click the link, he/she can go to `localhost/test` again.

Is there any standard or something?

Comment: A forward slash: `/`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, Thanks but '/' returns the root website. for example localhost/test/folder/some/index.php returns "localhost" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"../test"` solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try simply using a question mark:

```
<a href="?id=1">Link1</a>
<a href="?">Link without params</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I allways solved this with PHP. In PHP I would have a string variable named '$APP_ROOT' and assign the path to index.php to it. Then you can use this variable to print/echo it in the HTML.

Example (not sure if syntaxt is ok):

```
<?php
$APP_ROOT = 'localhost/test';
?>

<a href="<?php echo $APP_ROOT . '?id=1'; ?>">Link1</a>
<a href="<?php echo $APP_ROOT . '?id=2'; ?>">Link2</a>
```

With a template engine this could be cleaner. The $APP_ROOT variable needs to be changed when you deploy it to the server.

BUT maybe even more easy is the HTML [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). I dont know for sure if the base tag is good, I have never used it. Large amount of information is here: [Is it recommended to use the <base> html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag)

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I need the HTML one. The "../test" solved the problem. Thank you.